# (error) pipeline jenkins, invoke sh in a loop + serialization json

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I don't understand why an error occurs:

```
stage('name') {
    steps {
        script {
            def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( env.work_servers )
            for(item in jsonObj){
                cmd("my command --param1=${item.srv} --param2=${item.port}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getting an error, error stack https://pastebin.com/V09ZXrif

*even if you replace the cmd method call with sh, nothing changes*

If you invoke commands without a loop, everything works

```
stage('name') {
    steps {
        script {
            def srv = "..."
            def port = "..."
            cmd("my command --param1=${srv} --param2=${port}")

            srv = "..."
            port = "..."
            cmd("my command --param1=${srv} --param2=${port}")
        }
    }
}
```

this also works

```
stage('name') {
    steps {
        script {
            def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( env.work_servers )
            for(item in jsonObj){
                echo item 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
def cmd(command) {
    result = ""
    if (isUnix()) {
        result = sh(
            script: command,
            returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
    } else {
        bat "chcp 65001\n${command}"
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this problem, because `new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)` returns a map of type `groovy.json.internal.LazyMap`, which is not serializable. Any code you run inside stages has to operate on serializable objects. *(An exception can applied with extracted methods annotated with `@NonCPS`.)*

The solution to this problem is simple - replace `JsonSlurper` with `JsonSlurperClassic` which returns `HashMap` from the `parseText(text)` method.

```
stage('name') {
    steps {
        script {
            def jsonObj = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText( env.work_servers )
            for(item in jsonObj){
                cmd("my command --param1=${item.srv} --param2=${item.port}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to stay with `JsonSlurper` you can extract the part that parses JSON and does any operations with the JSON-object to a separate method and annotate it with `@NonCPS`. You can consider this alternative option if your JSON is a huge one and using `LazyMap` makes some sense. Otherwise, switching to `JsonSlurperClassic` is the best way to solve your problem.